# $_POST is not working in ajax form submit?

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

When I try to check user input name is already exist by ajax form submit !But it only get `Undefined index: username` in `sessions.php` ,what is missing ?

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="saveuser" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="username"><br>
<input type="password" name="pass"><br>
<input type="file" name="fileupload"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Confirm" id="confirm">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#confirm').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url :"sessions.php",
            data:$("#saveuser").serialize(),
            contentType : false,
            processData: false,            
            success: function(d){
                console.log(d);//[error] :Undefined index: username 
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

sessions.php

```
<?php
$exist = "david";
if($_POST['username'] == $exist){
    echo json_encode("Already exist");
}
else{
    echo json_encode("You can succesfully add");
}
?>
```

Comment: write print_r($_POST); in session.php  and did you find username in that array?

Comment: Is the Form which you have is in the same page

Comment: I got empty array ,but in the network tab I can see my parameters ! @Kaushalshah

Comment: it means your form value not Posted properly.

Comment: Yes there has! But no details explanation about using contentType :false @Yvette

Comment: @DavidJawphan The form is having a file upload field & also  `enctype="multipart/form-data"` which could be causing the data to be processed in some different manner.Additionally the file upload field doesnt make sense there because file wont get uploaded using your current code.

Comment: @DavidJorHpan Hi David, I was trying to answer your JS question... Avoid that by not putting anything in to the the browser's localStorage, the window object, cookies, etc... 

Here's a good read for you http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html

& Another: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Contributor_s_Guide/Private_Properties

Comment: Thanks so much @admcfajn

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are few issues with your code, such as:

- > ... it only get Undefined index: username in sessions.php

  The problem is because of the following two lines,

  ```
  contentType : false,
  processData: false,
  ```

  From [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/),

  > **contentType** (default: `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'`) 
  >   Type: `Boolean` or `String` 
  >   When sending data to the server, use this content type. Default is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8", which is fine for most cases. If you explicitly pass in a content-type to `$.ajax()`, then it is always sent to the server (even if no data is sent). As of jQuery 1.6 you can pass `false` to tell jQuery to not set any content type header.

  and

  > **processData** (default: `true`) 
  >   Type: `Boolean` 
  >   By default, data passed in to the data option as an object (technically, anything other than a string) will be processed and transformed into a query string, fitting to the default **content-type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"**. If you want to send a DOMDocument, or other non-processed data, set this option to `false`.

  Hence, `$_POST` array would be empty in **sessions.php** page if you set `contentType` and `processData` to `false`, and that's why you're getting this *undefined index: username* error. But having said that, since you're sending a file with your AJAX request, it's okay to set these settings as `false`, which is further explained in the following point.
- [`.serialize()`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method creates a URL encoded text string by serializing form control values, such as `<input>`, `<textarea>` and `<select>`. However, it doesn't include file input field while serializing the form, and hence your remote AJAX handler won't receive the file at all. So if you're uploading file through AJAX, use [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) object. But keep in mind that old browsers don't support FormData object. FormData support starts from the following desktop browsers versions: IE 10+, Firefox 4.0+, Chrome 7+, Safari 5+, Opera 12+.
- Since you're expecting a json object from server, add this setting `dataType:'json'` to your AJAX request. `dataType` is the type of data you're expecting back from the server.

So the solution would be like this:

Keep your **HTML** form as it is, and change your **jQuery/AJAX** script in the following way,

```
$('#confirm').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url : 'sessions.php',
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,            
        success: function(d){
            console.log(d.message);
        }
    });
});
```

And on **sessions.php** page, process your form like this:

```
<?php

    $exist = "david";
    if(isset($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['pass']) && !empty($_POST['pass'])){
        if($_POST['username'] == $exist){
            echo json_encode(array("message" => "Already exist"));
        }else{
            echo json_encode(array("message" => "You can succesfully add"));

            // get username and password
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $password = $_POST['pass'];

            // process file input
            // Check whether user has uploaded any file or not
            if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileupload']['tmp_name'])){

                // user has uploaded a file

            }else{
                // no file has been uploaded
            }
        }
    }else{
        echo json_encode(array("message" => "Invalid form inputs"));
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 12):

If you set **contentType** to **false**, ajax header is not send, in result if you send somehing `type:POST` header doesn't contain your data, so server can't see it. If you use `GET` to do it, it will work, because data is sended with `GET` (after url) not in header.

Just remove **contentType**

```
    $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url :"sessions.php",
            data: $("#saveuser").serialize(),
            success: function(d){
                console.log(d);
            }
    });
```

> **contentType**
>
> (default: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;
>   charset=UTF-8')
>
> Type: Boolean or String When sending data to the
>   server, use this content type. Default is
>   "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8", which is fine for
>   most cases. If you explicitly pass in a content-type to $.ajax(), then
>   it is always sent to the server (even if no data is sent). As of
>   jQuery 1.6 you can pass **false** to tell jQuery to not set any content
>   type header. Note: The W3C XMLHttpRequest specification dictates that
>   the charset is always UTF-8; specifying another charset will not force
>   the browser to change the encoding. Note: For cross-domain requests,
>   setting the content type to anything other than
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or text/plain
>   will trigger the browser to send a preflight OPTIONS request to the
>   server.

processData is used to send data as it is - [Ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

> Sending Data to the Server
>
> By default, Ajax requests are sent using the GET HTTP method. If the
>   POST method is required, the method can be specified by setting a
>   value for the type option. This option affects how the contents of the
>   data option are sent to the server. POST data will always be
>   transmitted to the server using UTF-8 charset, per the W3C
>   XMLHTTPRequest standard.
>
> The data option can contain either a query string of the form
>   key1=value1&key2=value2, or an object of the form {key1: 'value1',
>   key2: 'value2'}. If the latter form is used, the data is converted
>   into a query string using jQuery.param() before it is sent. This
>   processing can be circumvented by setting processData to **false**. The
>   processing might be undesirable if you wish to send an XML object to
>   the server; in this case, change the contentType option from
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded to a more appropriate MIME type.

Answer (score 4):

You are setting contentType to false, that is why PHP can not parse your post body

Answer (score 3):

Use $.post() for ajax :

```
$('#confirm').click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    $.post("sessions.php", $.param($("#saveuser").serializeArray()), function(data) { // use this ajax code
       console.log(data);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the following code in your html code and remove **contentType : false,
            processData: false**

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="saveuser" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="username"><br>
    <input type="password" name="pass"><br>
    <input type="file" name="fileupload"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Confirm" id="confirm">
</form>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-rc1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#confirm').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url :"sessions.php",
            data: $('#saveuser').serialize(),
            success: function(d){
                console.log(d);//[error] :Undefined index: username
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Considering this is your HTML form

```html
 
    <form method="POST" id="saveuser" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <input type="text" name="username" id="username"><br>
         <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass"><br>
         <input type="file" name="fileupload"><br>
         <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Confirm" id="confirm">
    </form>
```

You can call the jQuery function like this

```js
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-rc1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    jQuery("#saveuser").submit(function () {
    
      //Validate the input here
    
      jQuery.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: 'sessions.php',
       data: jQuery('#saveuser').serialize(),
    
       success: function (msg) {
        msg = jQuery.trim(msg);
        if (msg == 'Success') {
                       //Do Whatever     
                       //jQuery("#thanks_message").show('slow');
        }
       }
      });
      return false;
     });
```

You will get all the params in your session.php file like

```
<?php

  $username = trim($_POST['username']);
  $pass = trim($_POST['pass']);
  //rest of the params of the form

  $exist = "david";
  if ($username == $exist) {
    echo json_encode("Already exist");
  } else {
    echo json_encode("You can succesfully add");
  }
?>
```

I hope this resolves your problem.

Comment: I tried.
Cant run PHP snippet code but it works for me.

Comment: Unfortunately, since JS is sending post params to a PHP page that's why it doesn't work in Fiddle. I hope SO will implement PHP fiddle soon.

Answer (score 2):

```
<form method="POST" id="saveuser" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="username"/><br>
<input type="password" name="pass"/><br>
<input type="file" name="fileupload"/><br>
<input type="button" name="save" id="save" value="save"/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#save').click(function(e){
      var form = new FormData(document.getElementById('#saveuser'));  

      $.ajax({

            url :"sessions.php",
            type : 'POST',
            dataType : 'text',
            data : form,

            processData : false,
            contentType : false,  
            success: function(d){
                console.log(d);//[error] :Undefined index: username 
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your script:

Try using `new FormData` instead of `.serialize()`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#confirm').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData($("#saveuser")[0]);
      $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url :"tt.php",
            data:formData,
            contentType : false,
            processData: false,            
            success: function(d){
                console.log(d);//[error] :Undefined index: username 
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Note :** You are used `contentType` to `false` that mean jQuery not to add a Content-Type header. You are using jQuery's .serialize() method which creates a text string in standard URL-encoded notation. You need to pass un-encoded data when using "contentType: false".

Answer (score 0):

Change your script to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#confirm').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url :"sessions.php",
            data:$("#saveuser").serialize(),
            contentType : false,
            processData: false,            
            success: function(d){
                console.log(d);//[error] :Undefined index: username 
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your coding is correct.Remove processData and contentType  from Ajax it will work

```
processData : false,
contentType : false,
```

Answer (score -5):

Remove that **method,action: post  and blank from your form tag** as you need to give all details in ajax method only.

or you can delete the form tag itself as ajax method will take care of the post call.

this will solve hopefully

```
    <form id="saveuser" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: If `method="post"` is removed then how he will get `$_POST` variable values?

Comment: you are doing this by ajax if you are doing it with ajax you do not need form tag itself actually only ajax can do things.. posting variables and data  .. try this once..

Comment: @ Apb you don't need to put method and action attribute in form tag as you are submitting form using ajax method.

Comment: Yes. There is no need to write `method="post"` while submit form using `ajax`. If you didn't mentioned method it will consider as `GET` method by default. On submit click, all parameters details will be shown in URL. If you want to avoid this you need to metion `e.preventDefault();` on submit click.

Comment: that is because of action given there.. just remove form tag completely.. and you will not get any kind of these problems...(y)