# how to insert multipart career-form data with file uploading path and validation, using codeigniter and ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to insert job form data with file uploading and validation in php codeigniter via ajax but its not works. For reference my code is mentioned below.. please help me in regards.how can i send data to database with file.

---

> src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js">

### My HTML Form Code is:

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('MainController/submitjoinusForm', 'class="" id="joinusform"', $hidden = array());?>
        <div class="messages"> 
            <div class="col-md-12">
               <div id="status"></div>
           </div>
       </div>
       <div class="controls">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                <label for="contactname">Name</label>
                <input id="contactname" name="name" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Enter your name *" data-error="Valid name required." value="" type="text">                                           
                <!--  <span class="help-block with-errors"></span> -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                <label for="contactemail">Email Address</label>
                <input id="contactemail" name="email" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Enter your email *" value="" type="email">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                <label for="form_phone">Phone Number</label>
                <input id="contactphone" name="phone" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Enter your phone"  value="" type="tel">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                <label for="form_message">How Can We Help?</label>
                <textarea id="contactmessage" value="" name="message" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Message for us *" rows="5" 
                data-error="Leave us a message."></textarea>
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">                                       
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                <?php echo $captcha['image']; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">                                            
                <input type="text" id="contactcaptcha" value="" name="captcha" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Type Captcha..."> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                <input class="btn btn-secondary btn-send form-control" name="submit" value="Send message" type="submit">
            </div>                                   
        </div>
    </div>                                    
    </form>
```

### My Controller Code is

```
function submitjoinusForm() 
    {
        $response = array();
        $oword = $this->session->userdata('captcha_key');
        $tword = $this->input->post('captcha');
        //form field validation rules
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('fullname', 'Name', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('dob', 'Date of Birth', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('gender', 'Gender', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('maritalstatus', 'Marital Status', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('nationality', 'Nationality', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('visastatus', 'Visa Status', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('contact', 'Contact', 'trim|required');       
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('captcha', 'Captcha', 'trim|required');   

        if ( ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) && (strtolower($oword) == strtolower($tword)) )
        {
            if($_FILES['file']['error'] != 0) 
            {
                $response = array(
                    'status' => 'alert-danger',                 
                    'data'=> 'Please upload your CV file in pdf or word file, maximum size of 2MB.',
                );
                echo json_encode($response);
                return FALSE;
            }
            else
            {
                $config['upload_path']      = './files/';
                $config['allowed_types']    = 'pdf|doc|docx';
                $config['max_size']         = 1024 * 3;
                $config['encrypt_name']     = TRUE;
                $this->load->library('upload',$config);
                $this->upload->initialize($config);

                if ($this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
                {
                    $datafile['upload_data'] = $this->upload->data('userfile');
                    $userfile_name = $datafile['upload_data'];
                }
                else
                {
                    $userfile_name = '';
                }
                $data = array(

                    'fullname'      => $this->input->post('fullname'),
                    'dob'           => $this->input->post('dob'),
                    'gender'        => $this->input->post('gender'),
                    'maritalstatus' => $this->input->post('maritalstatus'),
                    'nationality'   => $this->input->post('nationality'),
                    'visastatus'    => $this->input->post('visastatus'),
                    'email'         => $this->input->post('email'),
                    'contact'       => $this->input->post('contact'),
                    'file'          => $userfile_name                   
                );              
                $this->joinusModel->submitJoinus($data);
                if($this->db->insert_id())
                {
                    $response = array(
                        'status' => 'alert-success',
                        'data' => "You message has been sent successfully. We'll get back to you shortly",
                    );
                    echo json_encode($response);
                }
                else
                {
                    $response = array(
                        'status' => 'alert-danger',
                        'data' => "Oops! Something went wrong while sending message to us.",
                    );
                    echo json_encode($response);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

### My javascript code is

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) 
    {
     $('#joinusform').ajaxForm( 
     {
       beforeSubmit: function(formData, jqForm, options)
       {
         $("div#status").html('');                 
     },
     $.ajax({
        url : $("#joinusform").attr('action'),
        dataType : 'json',
        type : 'POST',
        data : formData,
        contentType : false,
        processData : false,
    });     
     success:function(respnse)
     {             
      var result= $.parseJSON(respnse);
      $("div#status").html('<div class="alert '+result.status+' alert-dismissable" role="alert"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>'+result.data+'</div>');
      if (result.status == 'success') 
      {
        $('#contactform').clearForm();
    }
}           
});   
 });
```

Comment: some required fields are missing

Comment: in view form id is "contactform" and in ajax u r using  #joinusform

Comment: change this  $('#joinusform').ajaxForm.....  to  $('#contactform').ajaxForm.... in your js code

Comment: I changed the ID But still not working... it redirect to /submitjoinusForm controller function and shows blank white page...

Comment: can you add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute to `form` tag

Comment: i added multipart/form-data still not works...

Comment: Can you share what error you getting

Comment: My Suggestion can you try first only data then try with file so you will get exactly where is the issue

Comment: I tried the only form is working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've refactored your code a bit to make the errors more apparent by seperating somethings .etc. I found an error here: `$this->upload->data('userfile')` the optional parameter of data should only be for example be `file_name` or `full_path` but not the name of the file field.

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html#CI_Upload::data

I've also eliminated some `else` statements by testing for errors first and then exiting if they occur as you can see. If this continues to fail you should uncomment the first lines I've commented out to see if you are getting the input you should be. Please note, that files being sent via ajax need to be handled a certain way: [$_POST is not working in ajax form submit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37672531/post-is-not-working-in-ajax-form-submit).

```
function submitjoinusForm() {

    //echo '<pre>';
    //echo 'post data: <br>';
    //print_r($_POST);
    //echo 'files: <br>';
    //print_r($_FILES);

    $response = array();
    $oword = $this->session->userdata('captcha_key');
    $tword = $this->input->post('captcha');
    //form field validation rules
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('fullname', 'Name', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('dob', 'Date of Birth', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('gender', 'Gender', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('maritalstatus', 'Marital Status', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('nationality', 'Nationality', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('visastatus', 'Visa Status', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('contact', 'Contact', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('captcha', 'Captcha', 'trim|required');

    if (!$this->form_validation->run()) {
        echo json_encode(array('status' => 'alert-danger', 'data' => validation_errors('', '<br>')));
        exit;
    }

    if (strtolower($oword) !== strtolower($tword)) {
        echo json_encode(array('status' => 'alert-danger', 'data' => 'Incorrect captcha.'));
        exit;
    }

    $config['upload_path'] = './files/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf|doc|docx';
    $config['max_size'] = 1024 * 3;
    $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->initialize($config);

    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')) {
        $error = 'Please upload your CV file in pdf or word file, maximum size of 2MB. <br>';
        $error .= $this->upload->display_errors('', '<br>');
        echo json_encode(array('status' => 'alert-danger', 'data' => $error));
        exit;
    }

    $data = array(
        'fullname' => $this->input->post('fullname'),
        'dob' => $this->input->post('dob'),
        'gender' => $this->input->post('gender'),
        'maritalstatus' => $this->input->post('maritalstatus'),
        'nationality' => $this->input->post('nationality'),
        'visastatus' => $this->input->post('visastatus'),
        'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
        'contact' => $this->input->post('contact'),
        //https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html#CI_Upload::data
        'file' => $this->upload->data('file_name')
    );

    $this->joinusModel->submitJoinus($data);

    if ($this->db->insert_id()) {
        $response = array(
            'status' => 'alert-success',
            'data' => "You message has been sent successfully. We'll get back to you shortly.",
        );
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        $response = array(
            'status' => 'alert-danger',
            'data' => "Oops! Something went wrong while sending a message to us.",
        );
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You! @Alex for you support... i replace the code as per yours. now issue is when i all validation is pass correctly... and then i press submit button... nothing happened... when i inspect the error shows...in browser console 
Console Error: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)" is Something wrong with AJAX???

Comment: Turn on error reporting and in databade.php turn on db debug